# How to get longitude and latitude of my current location and display on two separate HTML form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, getlocation

Can anyone help with getting my current longitude and latitude on-click of a button, and display on two separate input form in HTML. Below is what my form will be like and on click of the "Get" button it will get my current LNG and LAT then display on forms 1 and 2.

```
<form>  


<button onclick="onFormSubmit()">GET CURRENT LOCATION</button>


<script>
function onGeoSuccess (position) {
        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var lng = position.coords.longitude;

        // NEXT 2 LINES WILL SET VALUE OF RESPECTIVE INPUTS
        document.getElementById('lat').value = lat;
        document.getElementById('lng').value = long;

        // MAKE API CALL HERE, OR ANY OTHER NEXT STEPS
    }

    function onGeoError (err) {
        console.error("Error while trying to get position", err);
    }

    function onFormSubmit () {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onGeoSuccess, onGeoError);
        } else {
            alert('GeoLocation not supported or not allowed');
        }
    }</script>

              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="lat" class="form-control" id="lat" placeholder="Your Latitude" data-msg="Please enter your latitude">
                <div class="validate"></div>
              </div>

<div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="lng" class="form-control" id="lng" placeholder="Your Longitude" data-msg="Please enter your Longitude">
                <div class="validate"></div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" id="contact-subject" placeholder="Subject" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 8 chars of subject">
                <div class="validate"></div>
              </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using some simple JavaScript:

```html
/* Add an onsubmit method to your form */
<form onsubmit="onFormSubmit()">
/*...*/
```

```js
function onGeoSuccess (position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;

    // NEXT 2 LINES WILL SET VALUE OF RESPECTIVE INPUTS
    document.getElementById('lat').value = lat;
    document.getElementById('lng').value = long;

    // MAKE API CALL HERE, OR ANY OTHER NEXT STEPS
}

function onGeoError (err) {
    console.error("Error while trying to get position", err);
}

function onFormSubmit () {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onGeoSuccess, onGeoError);
    } else {
        alert('GeoLocation not supported or not allowed');
    }
}
```

Comment: I followed your guide but LAT and LNG didn't show on my input, have updated my code above so you can see.

Comment: @mideveloper lots of things wrong with the code you updated - please try to provide cleaner and properly formatted code in the future. 

 You can see a [working example here](https://repl.it/@ayushyamitabh/NiceNecessarySnake#index.html) run this separately it might not work on the website itself as it's embedded

Comment: "Error while trying to get position". That is the error I got when I tried to run your code

Comment: I can guarantee the code works. Don't run it there, copy it to your file and then open it.   

For example - copy the code there to `index.html` and then open `index.html` in Chrome. When you click the button it will ask for permission to location.

Comment: Nope, geolocation is a browser API, you can [see compatible browsers here in docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: For some reason, the permission didn't pop up on my browser. I tried on my mobile device it pops up for some milliseconds and disappeared.

Comment: I checked my browser permission and set the location to allow but it will show the LAT and LNG in a flash and disappear.